# How to resolve injector module error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module

> Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=foo&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'foo'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dfoo%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1957%3A71%0Aensure%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1879%3A45%0Amodule%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1953%3A20%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4340%3A35%0AforEach%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A338%3A24%0AloadModules%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4324%3A12%0AcreateInjector%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4250%3A22%0AdoBootstrap%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1627%3A34%0Abootstrap%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1648%3A23%0AangularInit%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1542%3A14%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A28130%3A16%0Atrigger%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A2975%3A9%0AeventHandler%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ffoo%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3249%3A25

I have included below reference in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular-filter/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/select/select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ui-utils/ui-utils.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

and my js file looks like:

```
'use strict';

var fooApp = angular.module('foo', ['ui.utils', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'angular.filter', 'ui.select']);
```

Comment: post some code pal, the area where you think this error might be occuring. The link is broken by the way, and uses your cookies to get you the specifics

Comment: i have edited my question,with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `angular-cookies` in your index.html and then inject the `ngCookies` dependency.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-cookies.js">
```

Comment: i have included everything mentioned as dependency in my index.html,its quite a large list so have not copied the whole here.

Comment: Include angular.js file and show us the error... not the minified version?

Comment: sorry!i did not get u,i have included non minified version of angular.js

Comment: have you included ui-bootstrap library?

Answer (score 0):

In the module, you have to make sure that, you have included all the dependencies for the module 'app'

It shows that some of the dependencies are not loaded.

you have to include ngCookies in your app

please refer

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

or include `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-cookies.js">` in your index file after angularjs

Comment: I have ngCookies in my app and i have refrenced it in my index.html.